# problem with FPDF... $_POST not appearing

Tags: php, web, fpdf

The calling function from php does not work...

```
function Footer()
    {

$this->Cell($this->PG_W, 5, 'All quotes are valid for 30 days.  QUOTE EXPIRES: '**.$person["CA"]**, 0, 0, 'L');
}
```

.$person["CA"] - does not appear on the text

any ideas??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are inside a function, and an array named `$person` would not automatically be imported into its scope.

You would have to import `$person` into the function's scope using `global`, or pass it as a parameter, or as a property of the object you seem to be in.

Reference: [Variable scope in the PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: i know.. i have this - $person = mysql_fetch_array($result); and other ... but is this suppose to happen in fpdf?

Comment: @Norm is what supposed to happen in fpdf? I don't understand

Comment: i already have the global array from php but it still does not work... is there another global inside fpdf?